# Question on exam from Linear Algebra

Tags: linear-algebra

So I was running through some previous years' exams to practice, but I simply can't understand part (c.) of this [exam question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TL1pP.png).

**Exam Question:**

Let

$$\displaystyle A = \begin{pmatrix}
2 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 2 & 1 \\
-1 & 0 & 1 
\end{pmatrix}$$

a) Find the eigenvalues of $A$.

b) Determine a basis $\Gamma = \{v_1, v_2, v_3\}$ of $\mathbb{R}^3$ such that $A$ is diagonal with respect to $\Gamma$.

c) Give the matrices $\mathcal{M}(\mathrm{id}, \mathcal{E}, \Gamma)$ and $\mathcal{M}(\mathrm{id}, \Gamma, \mathcal{E})$.

---

These answers from link 2 and 3 are from the exam sheet and I understand a) and b) and I have also solved them myself, and gotten something different from b). But that is just because the ordering of columns is different, but the result should be correct too.
The eigenvalues of $A$ are $\lambda_1 = 2$ and $\lambda_2 = 1$. They have determined $\Gamma$ to be
[$\Gamma$](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f8qc8.png).
I got something a bit different, where $v_1$ and $v_3$ have different signs and I have also swapped the positions of $v_1$ and $v_2$. But my answer should still be correct right?

Then they answer c)
like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HiXpE.png)
I just don't understand how do they arrive at this answer. What is $\varepsilon$? And why do they just swap the 1st and 3rd column? Please someone explain. Thanks.

The book the definition comes from is "Linear Algebra Done Right" by Sheldon Axler.

Comment: Please do not use pictures for critical portions of your post. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not view-able to some, such as those who use screen readers.

Comment: If you decide to edit your post, expressing the math with [MathJax](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation), you can consult the answer of Martin Sleziak in [this sandbox](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/370/formatting-sandbox) as a guide for inserting a matrix into your posting.  Simply click on the `edit` link and **pretend** to edit the posting, to view the raw MathJax.  Be careful not to make/save any changes to the original posting.

Comment: The answer to c) mentions a definition 3.32. Could you transcribe it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $\mathcal{E}$ denotes the standard basis, which is given by $\mathcal{E}=\{e_1,e_2,e_3\}$, where
$$e_1=\begin{pmatrix}1 \\ 0 \\ 0\end{pmatrix} \ ; \ e_2=\begin{pmatrix}0 \\ 1 \\ 0\end{pmatrix};e_3=\begin{pmatrix}0 \\ 0 \\ 1\end{pmatrix}.$$
We know that $\Gamma=\{v_1,v_2,v_3\}$, where
$$v_1=\begin{pmatrix}1 \\ 0 \\ -1\end{pmatrix} \ ; \ v_2=\begin{pmatrix}0 \\ 1 \\ 0\end{pmatrix};v_3=\begin{pmatrix}0 \\ 1 \\ -1\end{pmatrix}.$$
It is not hard to show that
$$v_1=e_1-e_3 \ ; \ v_2=e_2 \ ; \ v_3=e_2-e_3.$$
and
$$e_1=v_1+v_2-v_3 \ ; \ e_2=v_2 \ ; \ e_3=v_2-v_3.$$
Using all these equations and the identity map $\text{id}:\Bbb R^3\to\Bbb R^3$, we can show that
\begin{align}
\text{id}(e_1)&=e_1=v_1+v_2-v_3;\\
\text{id}(e_2)&=e_2=v_2;\\
\text{id}(e_3)&=e_3=v_2-v_3.
\end{align}
Therefore, we can conclude that
$$\mathcal{M}(\text{id},\mathcal{E},\Gamma)=\begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 & 0\\ 1 & 1 & 1 \\ -1 & 0 & -1\end{pmatrix}.$$
We can find $\mathcal{M}(\text{id},\Gamma,\mathcal{E})$ in a very similar way.

Comment: I understand everything until your conclusion. How do you get the vectors $$
\begin{matrix}
1  \\
1  \\
-1  \\
\end{matrix}
$$
in M(id,$\varepsilon$,$\Gamma$)? I see that you can get it with $v_1+v_2$ but it doesn't happen anywhere.

Comment: @Tetoter Look carefully, I got the first column of the matrix $\mathcal M(\text{id},\mathcal E,\Gamma)$ from $\text{id}(e_1)=v_1+v_2-v_3$.

Comment: I don't get it. Doesn't that result in the vector $\begin{matrix}1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{matrix}$?

Comment: @Tetoter Of course not. You should read again the definition-$3.32$ in "Linear Algebra Done Right". By definition, the matrix of $\text{id}$ with respect to the bases $\mathcal{E}$ and $\Gamma$ is the 3-by-3
matrix $\mathcal M(\text{id},\mathcal{E},\Gamma)$ whose entries $A_{j,k}$ are defined by
\begin{align}
 \text{id}(e_1)&=A_{1,1}v_1+A_{2,1}v_2+A_{3,1}v_3;\\
 \text{id}(e_2)&=A_{1,2}v_1+A_{2,2}v_2+A_{3,2}v_3;\\
 \text{id}(e_3)&=A_{1,3}v_1+A_{2,3}v_2+A_{3,3}v_3.
\end{align}
Comparing these equations to the ones in my answer above, you will arrive at the same conclusion that I did.